# document.getElementById("p") is returning Null

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var obj1 = document.getElementById("p");
var obj2 = document.getElementById("btn");

alert(obj1);
alert(obj1);
```

This Code in JavaScript is returning null. I have both id 'p' and 'btn' in my html as Lable and Button respectively.

I have tried all other ways in my knowledge to solve this problem like

```
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function () {
            alert('Click..!!');
});


document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function () {
    alert('Click..!!');
};
```

and others including Jquery but can someone point why it is returing null instead of HTMLObject? Thanks.

UPDATE html as:

```
<body>
    <label id="p">L</label>
    <button id="btn" value="Click" >Click</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Add the relevant HTML to your question.

Comment: HTML Added in update

Comment: `<body onload="myFunction()">` and `<script>function myfinction(){var obj1 = document.getElementById("p");
var obj2 = document.getElementById("btn");

alert(obj1);
alert(obj1);}</script>`

Comment: This in-fact is a simple problem. I had this knowledge that I shall put the script at the place in HTML so that it should not be called before the button itself is rendered, which is a problem might most beginners face like me. And thanks tushar for linking with very clear and concise discussion and others..